# New install of Wordpress and civiCRM failed to open stream template_c / civi 5.37.0 on Synology NAS DS720+

Tags: wordpress, installation

I tried at least 5 times complete new installation on my Synology NAS, I always end up with the same errors. In Wordpress on the CiviCRM Tab it shows these errors: Please can someone help me.

```
Warning: include(/volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US//%%E6/E65/E656EDCD%%wordpress.tpl.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1273 

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US//%%E6/E65/E656EDCD%%wordpress.tpl.php' for inclusion (include_path='/volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/recaptcha/:/volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/financialacls/:/volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/eventcart/:/volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/greenwich/:.:/volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm:/volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages:/volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/auth_sasl:/volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/volume1/web/wordpre in /volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1273
```

Comment: Can you try deleting /volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/*  or check permission of /volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/ directory

Comment: Yes I deleted it, and it recreated the same. User http is the owner and have write rights, everyone also have write rights. The problem remains the same.

Comment: wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US why empty?